# Android add StateListDrawable programmatically as left checkmark in checkedTextView

Tags: android, checkedtextview, android-checkedtextview

Is there a way to dynamically add check mark as left check mark in checkedTextView using a StateListDrawable? via xml there is an attribute android:drawableLeft which puts the checkmark to the left, is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds() should work i guess.

Comment: setCompoundDrawable draws the drawable behind the text, haven't tried withIntrinsicBounds might work, but I don't see it being over-ridden in CheckedTextView's code